# How to open contact list with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, addressbook

How can I use VBA to do the same thing as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, Tools, Options, Custom and set a specific contact list as number one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Outlook TO button behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061455/change-outlook-to-button-behaviour)  ***(Same O.P.)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that in VBA - Outlook Object Model does not expose that functionality.

In Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), use [IAddrBook.SetDefaultDir](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc839797%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and set the [PR_AB_CHOOSE_DIRECTORY_AUTOMATICALLY](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stephen_griffin/2010/09/13/you-chosewisely/) property appropriately.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language - I am its author) is an option, you can use the [RDOAddressBook](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoaddressbook.htm).`DefaultAddressList` property:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set AddrList = Session.AddressBook.AddressLists.Item("Contacts")
Session.AddressBook.DefaultAddressList = AddrList
```

Comment: I only have access to Outlook and VBA. I have no admin privileges to install any "extras". Appreciate anyway.

Comment: You don't need admin privileges to install Redemption - it can install itself in HKCU when you register the dll with regsvr32.exe.

Comment: Ok. Didn't know that. Nevertheless it's not free right ?

Comment: The free version shows a nag screen. The distributable version does not.

Comment: And still need admin privileges to register de DLL right ? :-(

Comment: No, regsvr32 "full_path_to\redemption.dll" will be happy to install the dll in HKCU.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll give it a try :-)

Answer (score 2):

*Is this what your trying to do?*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olDialog As SelectNamesDialog
    Dim AL As AddressList

    Set olDialog = Application.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog
    Set AL = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists("Contacts")

    Debug.Print AL.GetContactsFolder

    With olDialog
        .InitialAddressList = AL
        .ShowOnlyInitialAddressList = True
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Well ... Not yet but I'm excited with the possibilities.. I want to do that but only when I'm creating an email And I press the button "TO". Does the "TO" Button have an event ? How can I use that function to replace that event ?

Comment: No, there is no way to modify the address book dialog shown when you click the To button. Namespace.GetSelectNamesDialog only works if it is your code showing the dialog.